# Using array in the onCreate returns null

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, null

I am getting some JSON data and parsing it into my object. Which I am trying to use to get all the fields I need. However I am getting a null on my arraylist and I am not sure why for example.

```
private List<MovieDetail> mMovieDetails;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    setupActionBar();


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    MovieDetail movieDetail = (MovieDetail) intent.getSerializableExtra(POSTER_TRANSFER);
    Glide.with(this).load(movieDetail.getPoster()).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_backdrop));

    ProcessMovieSearchImdbIDString processMovieSearchImdbIDString = new ProcessMovieSearchImdbIDString(movieDetail.getImdbID());
    processMovieSearchImdbIDString.execute();


    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_collapsing);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(movieDetail.getTitle());

       //this returns null which it shouldn't
    if(mMovieDetails !=null){
        for (MovieDetail detail: mMovieDetails) {
            Log.d("Details", "movie actors: " + detail.getActors());
        }
    }


    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_title)).setText(movieDetail.getTitle());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_writers)).setText(movieDetail.getWriter());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_actors)).setText(movieDetail.getActors());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_director)).setText(movieDetail.getDirector());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_genre)).setText(movieDetail.getGenre());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_released)).setText(movieDetail.getReleased());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_plot)).setText(movieDetail.getPlot());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_runtime)).setText(movieDetail.getRuntime());


}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public class ProcessMovieSearchImdbIDString extends JsonParse {
    public ProcessMovieSearchImdbIDString(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public void execute() {
        //super.execute();
        ProcessData processData = new ProcessData();
        processData.execute();
    }
    public class ProcessData extends DownloadSearchMovieImdbidJsonData {

        protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
            super.onPostExecute(webData);
             //this doesn't return null
            mMovieDetails=getMovies();
            for (MovieDetail detail : mMovieDetails) {
                Log.d("Details", "movie actors a: " + detail.getActors());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why its returning null when using the array in the onCreate method. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please update logcat too in case of crashes, helps to get to the problem quickly

Comment: you have not initialized `mMovieDetails` anywhere. I guess

Comment: i think you forgot to initialise mMovieDetails.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I have added a null check so it would not crash
I have now initialised the `private List<MovieDetail> mMovieDetails = new ArrayList<>();` however I am still not getting any values back @indramurari @vrundpurohit

Comment: How can you get values from an array of size 0? Where are you adding the data to this List??

Comment: I think the problem is that you are inflating the list in the `onPostExecute` method which runs in a different thread than background thread. while the `onPostExecute` is executing the background thread accessed the `movieList` and found it null because the list in not filled up yet.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I am adding the data to the list in the onPostExecute method

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez so what would be the best approach to fill the list?

Comment: you should move the logic of implementing list from `onCreate` to `onPostExecute`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez Thank you very much for your help. This makes alot of sense now and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution the problem is to move the list to onPostExecute which was mentioned by @M.WaqasPervez

Here is the code fix

```
    public class ProcessMovieSearchImdbIDString extends JsonParse {
    public ProcessMovieSearchImdbIDString(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public void execute() {
        //super.execute();
        ProcessData processData = new ProcessData();
        processData.execute();
    }
    public class ProcessData extends DownloadSearchMovieImdbidJsonData {

        protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
            super.onPostExecute(webData);

            mMovieDetails=getMovies();
            for (MovieDetail detail : mMovieDetails) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_title)).setText(detail.getTitle());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_writers)).setText(detail.getWriter());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_actors)).setText(detail.getActors());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_director)).setText(detail.getDirector());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_genre)).setText(detail.getGenre());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_released)).setText(detail.getReleased());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_plot)).setText(detail.getPlot());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_runtime)).setText(detail.getRuntime());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks all